# Is it possible to read content from own Android file system root directory with cordova/phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I want to know if it is possible to read files from the root directory as in Android `File Manager`? I want to create a music player and I want to read .mp3 files from the device, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FileSystem plugin for Cordova, https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file,  and access to the external storage on DeviceReady event like this

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, function(){alert("fail");});
```

then you can move into different directories creating readers and read their entries using the readEntries method.

For example, reading all the directories in external storage searching for "DCIM" directory

```
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            if (entries[i].name === "DCIM") {
                var dcimReader = entries[i].createReader();
                dcimReader.readEntries(onGetDCIM, function () {
        window.console.log("fail");
    });
                break; // remove this to traverse through all the folders and files
            }
        }
    }, function () {
        window.console.log("fail");
    });
}
```

Read fileSystem Plugin for more examples and documentation

Comment: Thank you very much) you save my time))